How to Identify the General Function from a Given Recurrence Relation?
I am currently working on a problem involving graphs, and I have derived a recurrence relation as part of my work. However, I am struggling to identify the general function that solves this recurrence relation. The specific recurrence relation I am dealing with is
\begin{align*}
    q_k(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)={1\over{n}} \big(\sum_{i=1}^k ((n_i-1) \mathbf{1}_{n_i>2}+p_s\mathbf{1}_{n_i=2})q_k(n_1,...,n_i-1,...,n_k)  \\
       +\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}p_p \mathbf{1}_{n_i=n_{i+1}=1}q_{k-1}(n_1,...n_{i},n_{i+1},...,n_k) \big)
\end{align*}
Where $\mathbf{1}$ is a Indicator function and $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k$ and $p_s$ and $p_p$ are two fix nummber with $p_p+p_s=1$
for exampel $q(1,1)$ is 1. and
\begin{align*}
    q_2(n_1,n_2)=p^{\#\{n_1,n_2\neq 1\}} {1\over n_1+n_2-1}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
    \#\{n_1,n_2,...,n_k\neq1\}
\end{align*}
denotes the number of elements in the set $\{n_1,...,n_k\}$ with do not equal 1.
.
I would like to know:

What are the general steps to solve this type of recurrence relation and find the explicit formula for ( q_k ) for any k?

Any insights, methods, or illustrative examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
